# How to prevent wx panels from overlapping on other sizers

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

Basically I am trying to accomplish a simple hide panel and show another on button click, I usually am able to do those if I have a single sizer in the frame but in this case I have a ribbon so I have 2 sizers in the frame and whenever I show a panel in sizer 2 it overlaps and shows as if it doesn't belong to a sizer.

I drafted a basic colored example to reproduce the issue, notice that when you click the button the blue panel hides the yellow one instead of replacing the  grey one.

```
import wx


class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "HomeFinance", size = (1400,700))
        self.panel1 = RibbonPanel(self)
        self.panel2 = SidePanel(self)
        self.panel3 = MainPanel(self)
        self.panel4 = NewPanel(self)

        self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(191, 193, 65))
        self.panel2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(56, 122, 45))
        self.panel3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(77, 84, 96, 0))
        self.panel4.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(55, 149, 153, 0))
        self.panel4.Hide()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.sizer.Add(self.panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.hsizer.Add(self.panel4, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.hsizer.Add(self.panel3, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.hsizer.Add(self.panel2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.hsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onetimer, self.panel2.m_button1)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.CenterOnScreen()
        self.Show()

    def onetimer(self, event):
        self.panel3.Hide()
        self.panel4.Show()


class RibbonPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(1400, 115), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
                 name=wx.EmptyString):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, style=style, name=name)
        self.Layout()

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(1000, 545), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
                 name=wx.EmptyString):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, style=style, name=name)
        self.Layout()


class SidePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(400, 545), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
                 name=wx.EmptyString):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, style=style, name=name)
        self.m_button1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"MyButton", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        self.Layout()


class NewPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(1000, 545), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
                 name=wx.EmptyString):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, style=style, name=name)
        self.Layout()

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The blue panel is expected to replace the grey one and have the exact same spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the widgets being displayed you need the sizer to calculate the new positions and sizes. Therefore, your code was only missing a call to `self.Layout()` in `onetimer`

The method should be:

```
def onetimer(self, event):
    self.panel3.Hide()
    self.panel4.Show()
    self.Layout()
```